# Rails devise not letting to log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree

everything seemed to work, but at some point it stopped and i havent done anything near devise configurations.

So the situation and the problem is that - when i register ( sign up ) for the first time, everything works and I go through sign in phase, also that account is succesfully stored at database. But if I log out and then try to login ( sign in ) with earlier created user parameters - I cant. And i dont even get any error messages or ect. Fields look like i entered password incorectlly but I'm 100% sure that I'm giving good parameters ( tried a lot of times ).

What might be wrong?

p.s. I'm also using spree_auth_devise, but those two have diferent modules, functions. So  I think they should not interfere with each other. but mby?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using the Confirmable module in Devise. You can either disable it, by removing `:confirmable` from your model. Or set a time period for which the user is allowed to login without confirming the account.

#### app/config/init/devise.rb

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days
```